# Creating a WCF project using an existing WSDL and svcutil.exe

Tags: vb.net, wcf, svcutil.exe

I am fairly new to authoring my own webserivces, so you'll need to bear
with me if I use incorrect terminology.

I am attempting to create a web service using WCF.  The service needs to be
created using an existing wsdl spec that can be found here:
    http://www.iicmva.com/IICMVA_CoverageVerification_.NET_1.0.wsdl

I was able to use svcutil.exe to create a class using this syntax:

```
svcutil IICMVA_CoverageVerification_.NET_1.0.wsdl /language:VB
```

I was also able to successfully use it in an old WebService project with an asmx page.
But we also need to secure the service using X509 certificates.  After some research 
I found that this is much eaiser to pull off using WCF, so I started attempting to use
that instead.  That's where I started to have problems.

I added the class created by svcutil.exe to a blank WCF project, and modified
the default Service1.svc to implement the new class.  I had to make a small tweak
that I don't really understand to get the project to run:

Change this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AutoserviceWCF3.VerifyServiceSoap">
```

to this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="VerifyServiceSoap">
```

The problem I immediately ran into was that running this project and clicking
on the wsdl link did not give me the full xml I was expecting.  With my asmx page,
I was able to see an XML page that looked very similar to the original wsdl
linked above.  In my new WCF project, I am left with a shell of a wsdl page.
I am able to see the bindings and the main interface, but I cannot see any
of the data definitions.

Here are the exact steps I have taken to get to my current status:

- Create a new WCF project
- Add VerifyService.vb created by svcutil.exe
- removed * from ReplyAction in VerifyService.vb --Found this online.  Didn't appear to do anything.
- Paste output.config generated by svcutil.exe into web.config
- blanked out address attribute of client.endpoint in web.config
- modify Service1.svc to implement VerifyServiceSoap
- Change this:

  ```
  <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AutoserviceWCF3.VerifyServiceSoap">
  ```
- to this:

  ```
  <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="VerifyServiceSoap">
  ```

That's pretty much it.  I've attempted several different tweaks with mixed results,
but am still no closer to getting this thing to function.

If I modify the VerifyService.vb created by svcutil.exe from this:

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0"), _
 System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.iicmva.com/CoverageVerification/", ConfigurationName:="VerifyServiceSoap")> _
Public Interface VerifyServiceSoap

    'CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper name (CoverageRequest) of message VerifyInsuranceRequest does not match the default value (VerifyInsurance)
    <System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://localhost:1101/AutoServicesWCF3/Service1", ReplyAction:=""), _
     System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()> _
    Function VerifyInsurance(ByVal request As VerifyInsuranceRequest) As VerifyInsuranceResponse
End Interface
```

To this:

```
<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface VerifyServiceSoap

    <OperationContract()> _
    Function VerifyInsurance(ByVal request As VerifyInsuranceRequest) As VerifyInsuranceResponse
End Interface
```

I am able to change this line of code back to how I expected it to look:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AutoserviceWCF3.VerifyServiceSoap">
```

It also adds a few things to the wsdl link, but it is still far from complete.

There is also this link of code in VerifyService.vb that seems a little off:

```
'CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper name (CoverageRequest) of message VerifyInsuranceRequest does not match the default value (VerifyInsurance)
```

Those are really the only clues I have right now.  Here is all the project code:

Service1.svc:

```
Public Class Service1
    Implements AutoServiceWCF3.VerifyServiceSoap

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Function VerifyInsurance(ByVal request As AutoServiceWCF3.VerifyInsuranceRequest) As AutoServiceWCF3.VerifyInsuranceResponse Implements AutoServiceWCF3.VerifyServiceSoap.VerifyInsurance
        Dim v As New AutoServiceWCF3.VerifyInsuranceResponse
        Return v
    End Function
End Class
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.

            Visual Basic options:
            Set strict="true" to disallow all data type conversions 
            where data loss can occur. 
            Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <clear/>
                <add namespace="System"/>
                <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
                <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
                <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
                <add namespace="System.Text"/>
                <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
                <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
            </namespaces>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the authentication service. Include 
              requireSSL="true" if appropriate.

          <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
          -->
                <!--
              Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service, and to choose the 
              profile properties that can be retrieved and modified in ASP.NET AJAX 
              applications.

          <profileService enabled="true"
                          readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                          writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
          -->
                <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the role service.

          <roleService enabled="true"/>
          -->
            </webServices>
            <!--
        <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
        -->
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>

    <!--Added bindings and client from output.config generated by svcutil.exe-->
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="VerifyServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VerifyServiceSoap"
          contract="VerifyServiceSoap" name="VerifyServiceSoap" />
    </client>

    <services>
            <service name="AutoServiceWCF3.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="AutoServiceWCF3.Service1Behavior">
                <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!--removed AutoServiceWCF3. from contract-->
                <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="VerifyServiceSoap">
                    <!--
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="AutoServiceWCF3.Service1Behavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

VerifyService.vb:

This character limit is preventing me from putting this in here.  It was created with
this command against the wsdl file linked at the top of my post:

```
svcutil IICMVA_CoverageVerification_.NET_1.0.wsdl /language:VB
```

The svcutil I used was located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin

The code it generates says:
svcutil 3.0.4506.2152

Edit:
After a lot of guesswork and manual mofications to the vb class created by svcutil.exe, we were
able to get something that worked.  Here is what we had to do.

Replaced this:

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0"),  _
 System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.iicmva.com/CoverageVerification/", ConfigurationName:="VerifyServiceSoap")>  _
Public Interface VerifyServiceSoap

    'CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper name (CoverageRequest) of message VerifyInsuranceRequest does not match the default value (VerifyInsurance)
    <System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://tempuri.org/VerifyInsurance", ReplyAction:="*"),  _
     System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()>  _
    Function VerifyInsurance(ByVal request As VerifyInsuranceRequest) As VerifyInsuranceResponse
End Interface
```

with this:

```
<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface VerifyServiceSoap

    <OperationContract()> _
    Function VerifyInsurance(ByVal request As VerifyInsuranceRequest) As VerifyInsuranceResponse
End Interface
```

Replaced everything that looked like this:

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "3.0.4506.2152"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute(),  _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),  _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.iicmva.com/CoverageVerification/")>  _
Partial Public Class RequestorInformationModule
```

with this:

```
<DataContract()> _
Partial Public Class RequestorInformationModule
```

Replaced everything that looked like this:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order:=0)>  _
```

with this:

```
<DataMember()> _
```

We also basically threw out everything that svcutil.exe created in output.config and ended up with this
as our web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.

            Visual Basic options:
            Set strict="true" to disallow all data type conversions 
            where data loss can occur. 
            Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <clear/>
                <add namespace="System"/>
                <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
                <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
                <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
                <add namespace="System.Text"/>
                <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
                <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
            </namespaces>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
 <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>

   <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService2.VerifyServiceBehavior" name="WcfService2.VerifyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService2.VerifyServiceSoap">
     <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
     </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   </service>
  </services>



        <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfService2.VerifyServiceBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

After making all these changes, we were able to implement the class properly.  This worries me though, because
if the source wsdl changes and we need to reimport and implement it, we will need to redo this whole
process of manually fixing the file.  It's around 3000 lines of code, so it took quite a while.  This seems to 
defeat the purpose of the wsdl file.  There has got to be an easier way to do this.  I'm wondering if we 
should have used something other than svcutil.exe.  Can anybody shed some light on what we are missing here?